# sqlite3 query works on command line, fails in Node

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

The below code fails in Node/express with the error message: `SQLITE_ERROR: near "%": syntax error`

```
async function performSearch(term) {

  const searchQuery = 
    `select foo from bar where quux like %?% and baz = ?`;

  let result;
  try {
    result = await connection.query(searchQuery, [term1, term2]);
  } catch (e) { 
    console.error(e.message); 
  }
  return result;
}

/* code for using promises with sqlite adapted from
 * https://dev.to/michelc/use-sqlite3-in-async-await-mode-57ke */
connection.query = function (sql, params) {
  var that = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    that.all(sql, params, function (error, rows) {
      if (error)
        reject(error);
      else
        resolve(rows);
    });
  });
};
```

I'm using the same way of binding parameters with queries that don't use the `%` wildcard with success. Also, the same query works fine in the command line tool.

I tried enclosing the search term in singlequotes like `'%?%'` but then I got this error instead:

`SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range`

Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must concatenate the wildcards `'%'` to the placeholder `?`:

```
select foo 
from bar 
where quux like '%' || ? || '%' and baz = ?
```